# Regular expression for retrieving http:// from the given URL

Tags: java, regex

I want to retrieve http:// or https:// as per the protocol being used  from the given URL.

How can i do it using Pattern and a Matcher?

If there's some other way to do it then suggest me the snippet.

here is my URL
[https://www.google.co.in/#q=retrieving+http:%2F%2F+from+url+using+java+regular+expression+](https://www.google.co.in/#q=retrieving+http%3a%2F%2F+from+url+using+java+regular+expression+)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
String urlString = "https://www.google.co.in";
URL url = new URL(urlString);
String protocol = url.getProtocol();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply something like

```
^(https?://)
```

should match